# How to add placeholder text to Edit in a Python FMX GUI App?

Tags: python, user-interface, firemonkey, property-placeholder

I have made a `Form` with an `Edit` component using the [DelphiFMX GUI Library for Python](https://github.com/Embarcadero/DelphiFMX4Python) and I'm trying to add a placeholder text to the Edit component, but I'm not sure how. I've tried doing `self.myEdit.Placeholder = "Enter your name..."`, but this just gives me an error of `AttributeError: Error in setting property Placeholder`.

Here's my full code:

```
from delphifmx import *

class frmMain(Form):
    def __init__(self, owner):
        self.Caption = 'My Form'
        self.Width = 400
        self.Height = 200
        
        self.myEdit = Edit(self)
        self.myEdit.Parent = self
        self.myEdit.Align = "Center"
        self.myEdit.Width = 250

        self.myEdit.Placeholder = "Enter your name..."


def main():
    Application.Initialize()
    Application.Title = "My Application"
    Application.MainForm = frmMain(Application)
    Application.MainForm.Show()
    Application.Run()
    Application.MainForm.Destroy()

main()
```

My `Edit` is just empty. I need a placeholder text to be in there.

Is placeholder text available? How do I add placeholder text to the Edit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In FMX, the `Placeholder` text is called `TextPrompt`. So you can simply do:

```
self.myEdit.TextPrompt = "Enter your name..."
```

And that should work as can be seen by the attached screenshot:
[image: Python GUI with placeholder edit]