# How do I add placeholder text for a Memo in a Python FMX GUI App?

Tags: python, firemonkey, memo, property-placeholder

When using `TextPrompt` on my `Edit` like in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75609145/2908017), then it works, but using `TextPrompt` for my `Memo` does not work. When using it on my Memo, I get an error:

> AttributeError: Error in setting property TextPrompt

Here's my full code:

```
from delphifmx import *

class frmMain(Form):
    def __init__(self, owner):
        self.Caption = 'My Form'
        self.Width = 400
        self.Height = 200        
        self.Padding.Top = 20
        self.Padding.Right = 20
        self.Padding.Bottom = 20
        self.Padding.Left = 20
        
        self.myEdit = Edit(self)
        self.myEdit.Parent = self
        self.myEdit.Align = "Top"
        self.myEdit.TextPrompt = "Enter your name..."

        self.myMemo = Memo(self)
        self.myMemo.Parent = self
        self.myMemo.Align = "Client"
        self.myMemo.Margins.Top = 20
        self.myMemo.TextPrompt = "Enter your bio..."

def main():
    Application.Initialize()
    Application.Title = "My Application"
    Application.MainForm = frmMain(Application)
    Application.MainForm.Show()
    Application.Run()
    Application.MainForm.Destroy()

main()
```

The line that fails is:

```
self.myMemo.TextPrompt = "Enter your bio..."
```

---

Why is it working on the `Edit`, but not on the `Memo`? How do I add a placeholder on a Memo?

Comment: I know nothing about Python, but a Firemonkey `TMemo` does not have a `TextPrompt` property, so that's probably the cause of your error.